# Limit character after point in Java

Tags: java, android, character, point

How can I limit number of characters after point (which is displayed in my  TextView)
It would be greate to see 2 ways: in java and ectually in TextView XML (if it possible)
Thanks!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inivVars();     
}
private void inivVars(){...}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bCount:

        try{
        checkT1 = et1.getText().toString();
        checkT2 = et2.getText().toString();
        checkK1 = ek1.getText().toString();

        det1 = Float.parseFloat(checkT1);
        det2 = Float.parseFloat(checkT2);
        dek1 = Float.parseFloat(checkK1);
        float x = det2/(det1/100)/100*dek1;
        String sx = String.valueOf(x);
        text.setText(sx);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(CivilProtectActivity.this, "enter all values or use suitable '.'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

        }

        break;
    case R.id.bHide:
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et1.getWindowToken(), 0);
        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
        ek1.setText("");
        text.setText("");

        break;
    }}}
```

and TextView XML which displays data

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvShowA"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:hint="X"
    android:background="@drawable/sun"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android:minLength="30"   to set maximum character length to 30 **(put number you want to set)**

example

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvShowA"
    android:minLength="30"    //    See this
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:hint="X"
    android:background="@drawable/sun"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks! Your advice led me to the answer. Actually I needed  `android:maxLength="4"` in my textView to get _2,03_ instead of _2,0340923409_

Answer (score 0):

For controlling of precision I would recommend to use BigDecimal.

Here is example of limiting number of characters after point in Java application:
https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/calculator/blob/fee1b741aa74d659b8e30ad66d26d9ca6a2f6bc5/src/main/java/com/github/plokhotnyuk/calculator/CalculatorModel.java

Comment: Frankly it's too complicated for me now.) But I'll get onto it a few later. Thanks too.